# Java HashMap overwriting previous values

Tags: java, hashmap

so I'm trying to loop through and store a set of coordinates into a hashmap with an integer key. However, the hashmap is appearing to map the final pair of coordinates to every key so that when I loop through and get each pair at the end, they are all the same. The code is below, any help would be great! Thanks!

```
public HashMap<Integer,int[]> tiles;

public Board() 
{
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 600));
    tiles = new HashMap<Integer,int[]>();
    setTiles();
}

public void setTiles() {
        int[] coords = { 525, 525 };
        Integer square;
        for (square=1;square<=9;square++) { 
            System.out.println(square+": "+coords[0]+",, "+coords[1]);
            tiles.put(square,coords);
            int[] coord = tiles.get(square);
            System.out.println(square+": "+coord[0]+"; "+coord[1]);
            coords[0] = coords[0] - 50;
        }
        tiles.put(square,coords);
        for (square=11;square<=19;square++) {
            System.out.println(square+": "+coords[0]+",, "+coords[1]);
            tiles.put(square,coords);
            int[] coord = tiles.get(square);
            System.out.println(square+": "+coord[0]+"; "+coord[1]);
            coords[1] = coords[1] - 50;
        }
        tiles.put(square,coords);
        for (square=21;square<=29;square++) {
            System.out.println(square+": "+coords[0]+",, "+coords[1]);
            tiles.put(square,coords);
            int[] coord = tiles.get(square);
            System.out.println(square+": "+coord[0]+"; "+coord[1]);
            coords[0] = coords[0] + 50;
        }
        tiles.put(square,coords);
        for (square=31;square<=39;square++) {
            System.out.println(square+": "+coords[0]+",, "+coords[1]);
            tiles.put(square,coords);
            int[] coord = tiles.get(square);
            System.out.println(square+": "+coord[0]+"; "+coord[1]);
            coords[1] = coords[1] + 50;
        }
        tiles.put(square,coords);
        for (square = 1;square<=40;square++) {
            int[] coord = tiles.get(square); 
            System.out.println(square+": "+coord[0]+"/ "+coord[1]);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are reusing the same array instance for all keys. It's better to `put` a copy of the array each time. For example:

```
tiles.put(square, Arrays.copyOf(coords, 2));
```

instead of

```
tiles.put(square, coords);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are placing the same `int[]` into the `HashMap` over and over again.  So the last modification is visible through all keys of the `HashMap`.

The `put` operation doesn't place a copy of the value into the map, it places a reference to the object.  You have lots of references to the same `int[]`.

Instead, assign a new array to `square` after adding the array, so that references to separate arrays are `put` into the `HashMap`.